# <pre> tag automatically added - HTMLCodeFormat() and HTMLEditFormat()

Tags: coldfusion, tinymce

I have a form with several TinyMCE textareas. Content is loaded in some textareas when the form is called. Other textareas are empty.

The content that is preloaded into the text fields already has a `<p>` tag. Everything is fine with it. But i have a problem with the empty textareas. TinyMCE automatically adds a `<pre>` tag, which destroys the formatting and layout.

This is the process that leads to the problem:

1. Open the form and enter unformatted text to a empty textarea.
2. Save the form. The content is displayed correctly. Everything is fine so far.
3. Edit the form / content.

At this point, TinyMCE adds the `pre` tag. The tag is not yet saved in the database, it comes from the editor.

I also made some tests with preloaded content. This is the result.

```
Template code | TinyMCE textarea

<p>test</p> | <p>test</p>
test | <pre>test</pre>
```

How can I prevent TinyMCE  from adding the `<pre>` tag? Alternatively, `<pre>` could also be replaced by `<p>`.

Comment: I have never seen TinyMCE just add a `<pre>` tag to its content.  Can you use TinyMCE Fiddle or JS Fiddle to show this in action?

Comment: My version 4.0.12 is not available in the dropdown on TinyMCE Fiddle. I tried the other 4.0.x versions and noted, that it adds a p tag instead of pre.

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/djgaab

I updated to 4.0.28, but TinyMCE doesnt work anymore on the site. I am working on it.

Comment: The language files were missing, now 4.0.28 works. But i have still the problem. In the database is "test". And in the source code of the page suddenly stands "<pre>test</pre>". My code does not do that. Dont know where it comes from.

Comment: If the page's source code has the `<pre>` tags that is happening before TinyMCE is initialized so its somewhere in your application.

Comment: You are right. I was confused, because i dont use any pre tag in the application. I found my mistake. I used HTMLcodeFormat() instead of HTMLeditFormat(), which adds these pre tags. Thank you for leading me to the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem was the use of HTMLCodeFormat instead of HTMLEditFormat before I handed the content over to TinyMCE. Both have nearly the same effect, but HTMLCodeFormat adds a `<pre>` tag in addition.

[HTMLCodeFormat()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/htmlcodeformat.html)

[HTMLEditFormat()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/htmleditformat.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you're on ColdFusion 10 or later, you should be using the OWASP ESAPI encoding functions. They handle a higher range of character encoding than `HTMLEditFormat()` and `HTMLCodeFormat()`.

Output between HTML tags: `<td>#encodeForHTML(variables.myVar)#</td>`

Output in an HTML attribute: `<input type="text" value="#encodeForHtmlAttribute(variables.myVar)#">`